# How to include a specific one include file in GCC or clang search path?

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang

I have tons of C source code which includes a system header file, like that:

```
#include <sys_header.h>
```

Also I have a library (let's call it `better_lib`) where this specific header works much better for my code, but there are also many other files in the folder of this library. I want to use all the regular includes for my C sources, but this file only should be used from `better_lib`. I'm confident that this mix will work great, but the problem is:

How do I make GCC use `sys_header.h` from `better_lib/include` and use all other includes whatever they are (maybe `<string.h>`, `<math.h>` etc) from standard locations? If I use the `-I` option, I'll override all the standard headers, which is not viable. If I use the `-include` option, I'll include that file for all the source files, not only for those that actually need it. Since it's >20000 source lines, it will slow down compilation more than I'll tolerate.

I have no control over the `better_lib/include` folder, it will be updated from time to time, and I cannot remove all the files apart the one that I need. I also cannot create new include directories or move/symlink the header I need to another location. I need a flag that I'll globally add to `CFLAGS` that will work like `-I` but at a file-only level. Is there one?

Comment: A 20000+ line *header* file? Can you add `-include` only for the files that need it (via target-specific make variables)?

Comment: Yes, this is a header file. It is a generated compatibility layer with another subsystem. Like a replacement of X11 with wayland, or Qt5 instead of Qt3. And actually the source code in question is not under my control, I just need to facilitate its transition to the new header without requiring a developer of each C (or C++, does not matter) module to fix their sources or makefiles. I need to fix the build system for the transition to be transparent. I agree that all this is a very strange case, but It seems impossible to implement a different design decision.

Comment: Then I would look into whether you can manually add `-include` for that file to the targets representing the files that need it. It might be possible (though a bit ugly and a maintenance burden) to do it.

Comment: So far, I can only say whether a particular module needs that file, and apply `-include` to the whole module, since there happens to be a define required to use this module (luckily). Not the worst solution, but not the best one either.